# How to make windows application for single system(machine)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I want to make .exe for desktop application which can only used once in whole life.Nobody can run it twice.

Comment: As I understand it, you want each user to run it only once.I don't think that's possible. The user could have several computers, or a virtual machine setup, and would be able to run it more than once. You could use some sort of serial key, but that's also breakable (there are many questions about serials on SO, you can see the pros and cons there)

Comment: User have only computer.It only can run again in same system not in any other.

Comment: simples: [write skynet](http://xkcd.com/534/)... only need one of those and *poof* no more world.

Comment: (joking aside, what @Rox said; taking into account VMs, backups, spoofing, etc - that seems a pretty high aim)

Comment: @Marc: Is it bad I heard you say that in my head with voice of  meerkat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do that reliably.

You may try simple stuff like writing a magic key in the registry or storing a magic file somewhere, but simple tools like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will show your magic markers to anyone with Google skills.

You may try to delete the .exe when it is terminating, but if the user makes a copy before they execute your file, you loose again.

You may write a root-kit that prevents the system from launching your application twice, but that is not very nice and it can be detected and circumvented too.

You may create an online service where your application needs check for a one time license to execute, but that can be cracked and you will get a big mess keeping track of one time licenses.

But in the end, if someone really wants to run your application more than once they will figure out how to do it.

How much protection do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Delete itself as it exits?

Comment: Better yet, delete once it's completely loaded. That's pretty much the only way I'd say.

Comment: Couldn't the exe be copied before first run, so the backup would always be available?

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is a single instance application that can start up, and no other copy can run - the single instance start up code is based on creating a mutex, and if another copy is run, it checks to see if the mutex is allocated, if it is, it bails out and exits immediately. Have a look at this article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/singleinstance.aspx) that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: "only used once in whole life. Nobody can run it twice." - from this I understood that he doesn't want the program to be started again after the first run.

Comment: @Rox: that is the idea of using a global mutex allocated by the system...once it's allocated, that's it... no other copy can run...

Comment: The "in whole life" suggests this isn't quite what the OP intends.

Comment: @Marc: hmmmm the computer running on infinite energy powered by dilithium crystals?

Comment: as I understood, he wants the user to be able to use the program only once: start, do stuff, close the app and that's it. If he tried to start it again after closing it, he wouldn't be able to. That's what I tried to say with the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a combination of DPAPI calls ([`ProtectedData` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c64xe0y.aspx)) to push a value into the registry to check for a second time, or alternatively encode a value on first run and check the result matches the machine you intend it to be run on (and exit if not).

See [`DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope.aspx). The result of the protected data will be almost always different per machine, so this works as a specific-machine check.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a registry key. If the key exists abort execution.